# Share directives between location blocks in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have an `nginx` location block that should be delegated to `uwsgi` backend **and** provide `http` --> `https` redirection, so it goes as follows:

```
location  ~ ^/(api/v1) {
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
     access_log my-access.log;
     error_log my-error.log;
     include uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
     uwsgi_send_timeout 300;
     uwsgi_param ..;
     uwsgi_param ..;
     etc ...
    }
```

What I want, is for a specific endpoint **not** to provide `https` redirection, so I am forced to do the following:

```
location  = /api/v1/my/more/specific/endpoint {
     access_log my-access.log;
     error_log my-error.log;
     include uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
     uwsgi_send_timeout 300;
     uwsgi_param ..;
     uwsgi_param ..;
     etc ...
    }
```

}

Is there a way `nginx` allows to avoid the above duplication of `uwsgi` parameters definition?

Comment: All of those parameters can be inherited from the `server` block level. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 options:

1. Move the params that have `server` context and must affect all locations our of the `location` block to the `server` block
2. Use [include](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) to share common code to avoid copy & paste

> Includes another file, or files matching the specified mask, into
>   configuration. Included files should consist of syntactically correct
>   directives and blocks.